# Symfony 4 - Submit Ajax form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

on my project Symfony 4 I have a page where I fill a form. In this one, I have to select a vehicle at a certain moment. I would like to offer the user the possibility to add one in ajax to the right of the "Vehicle" field. As soon as it is added in database, he also adds to his list so that he can select it. I watched a tutorial to do pretty much the same thing. I created my function in my controller, and I manage to generate the modal window with the form to enter a new vehicle. But I can not really submit it and make it appear in the list.

Currently, I've this :

[image]

It is to add a vehicle in database, and that it appears in the list of the field of my main form. The field "Véhicule de service" (the last field).

So, I did this :

I created a function controler for adding vehicle :

```
/**
     * Pour créer un nouveau véhicule
     * 
     * @Route("/manage/ordreMission/new/new_vehicule", name="vehicule_create")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     * @return Response
     */
    public function createVehicule(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $vehicule = new Vehicule();

        $form = $this->createForm(VehiculeType::class, $vehicule, [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl($request->get('_route'))
        ])
            ->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $manager->persist($vehicule);
            $manager->flush();
            return $this->json([
                'code' => 200,
                'message' => 'OK',
                'vehicule' => $vehicule,
            ], 200);
        }

        return $this->render('ordre_mission/partials/newVehicule.html.twig', [
            'formVehicule' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

I created my form view in Twig :

```
{# ordre_mission/partials/newVehicule.html.twig #}
{# http://127.0.0.1:8000/manage/ordreMission/new/new_vehicule #}

{{form_start(formVehicule)}}
{{ form_widget(formVehicule) }}
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-label="Enregistrer">
            Enregistrer
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
{{ form_end(formVehicule) }}
```

And in my principal Twig view ( with the first form ), I added a modal and Ajax to add my vehicle :

```
   {% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {{form_start(form)}}
    {{form_row(form.user)}}
    {{form_row(form.accompagnateur)}}
    {{form_row(form.entreprise)}}
    {{form_row(form.lieu)}}
    {{form_row(form.motif)}}
    {{form_row(form.date)}}
    {{form_row(form.transport)}}
    {{form_row(form.immatriculationVehiculeService)}}
    {# champs où je vais pouvoir ajouter un véhicule #}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
    {{form_end(form)}}

    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        Ajouter un véhicule
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalTitle">Ajout d'un article</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ajax-results">here comes the result</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({placeholder: 'Choisissez un agent', allowClear: true, language: 'fr'});
    </script>

    <script>
        $('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            var modal = $(this);
            $.ajax('{{ path('vehicule_create') }}', {
                success: function (data) {
                    modal.find('.modal-body').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
        $(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e.target.id);

            var id = e.target.id;

            if(id == "formVehicule")
            {

                $formVehicule = $(e.target);
                modal = $('#exampleModal');


                var $submitButton = $formVehicule.find(':submit');
                $submitButton.html('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');
                $submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

                $formVehicule.ajaxSubmit({
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.message == 'OK') {
                            var sel = document.getElementById("ordre_mission_immatriculationVehiculeService");
                            var opt = document.createElement('option');
                            opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.vehicule.vehiculeString));
                            opt.value = data.vehicule.immatriculation;
                            sel.appendChild(opt);
                            modal.modal('toggle');
                        } else {
                            modal.find('.modal-body').html(data);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                        $submitButton.html(button.data('label'));
                        $submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                e.target.submit();
            }

        });

    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

UPDATE : (I updated my code, you can see it)

So everything works. But it's not clean, I think.
The problem is that when I submitted the main form, it also entered the listener when it should not.
So I had to add an ID to the vehicle creation form, and in the listener, I had to make a condition:

If the form ID matches the vehicle's creation ID, then it can launch the listener code. Otherwise, he must submit the form normally.

Except that I do not know if it's clean ... And most importantly, I risk being led to add another possibility of adding an object by a modal. So it's going to be more and more complicated, is not it?

Comment: Can you please add the route file code? No route found error means you are not specifying route as POST. See here https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#matching-http-methods

Comment: Okay, I updated my first post. But is it really a problem ? Because in my controller function, I added the route, no ?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that part. You are missing the method type in the controller annotation. So i think this should solve this missing route problem  @Route("/manage/ordreMission/new/new_vehicule", name="vehicule_create", condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()", methods={"GET","POST"}).

Comment: Don't know if that will fix it @MuhammadTashfeen, by default, routes can handle any type of request. I believe `methods` flag is only for limiting the types of request.

Answer (score 1):

Your error shows that symfony can't find a route for

> "POST /manage/ordreMission/new/new_vehicule" (from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/manage/ordreMission/new")

Your route seem good so either you are not sending a "POST" request (you can check using the Network Profiler in your Browser) or your JS code is not working properly and you may actually send a request which is not XmlHttpRequest().
Try to remove condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()" in your route definition to see if it works.

Comment: Okay I removed the ", condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()", and now, it works ! I've my new Vehicle in my database ! But suddenly I am redirected to a blank page with writing "success". I guess it's because in my controller I tell him to send me a response "success" if successful. But suddenly how could I not be redirected, and make sure my last field is "updated"?

Comment: If your page is reloaded, that because you are not sending XmlHttpRequest. It's a normal post (the same as when you send a form). 
So either your JS or your html is not correct.
And yes your controller should return a JsonResponse.

Comment: Oh okay, and in my JsonResponse, I have to return what ? The new object maybe ?

Comment: I return a json now. But my page is going to the blank page with json response. I'm a beginner in Ajax, I don't know how can I block the redirection

Comment: Can you try to comment your ajax function ($formVehicule.ajaxSubmit({...}))
 and see if the form is still sent ?

Comment: I tried, and yes, it is still sent, and I've still the blank page with json

Comment: Ok, so that means that $(document).on(...) is not working. Do you have "submit" in your console from  console.log("submit"); ?

Comment: Submit in my console from console.log("submit") ? Sorry I don't understand :/. You want to know if I Can make a console.log() when I'm in the $(document).on.... ? (PS: Sorry for my bad english I'm french)

Comment: Yes, you have to check if your $(document).on(...) is working (if you enter the listener when you send the form).

Comment: It's good I solved the problem! I had to put 'form' instead of 'formVehicule' in the document. Can you see my first post? I edited it, I have one more thing to do.

Comment: Try like that : https://codepen.io/LeVerbeux/pen/ZEEKZxE. About the security, you must keep in mind that a user can still modify your js on his browser (event if it has been uglyfied). The front js must be used only to help user to perform (or to not perform) actions. No security behavior can be trusted in front end. So the new way is not worse than the old one (in matter of security).

Comment: Super it works better thank you! And if I am led to add another modal to add an object of another entity in this form, would there be something to do so that I can determine which form can be submitted?

On security, I see what you mean. After, I do not see what the user could do on this page?